# How can I take a screenshot of only the client area of a window?

Tags: windows, screenshot

How to take a screenshot without the title bar using a single shortcut?

Related [Closed Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/531883/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-only-the-client-area-of-a-window).

Comment: Questions older than 60 days are not eligible for migration. If you have a problem you are trying to solve then it is best to ask your own question. Please make it complete and self contained rather than requiring people to go hunting for what it is you are asking. You might also want to read the [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) to ensure your question contains all the information required for someone to answer it here.

Comment: Please edit your question and tags to specify an operating system, and if you're looking for gratis or commercial software.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Python solution using win32gui modules.
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/SmartManoj/245130d9558c700cb6d7f65b8b81df1d)

Answer (score 1):

I use [screenrec](https://screenrec.com/).  It is free.  I am not associated with it.  I can't take a screenshot of it, but here's a shot of just the client area of the browser using it.  It will also record audio and video from a window (unless it has been protected), and more.

It is cross-platform for Linux, macOS, and Windows.

[image: successful screenshot of a window without the titlebar]

Comment: One should select the region in this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows.

Start > Snipping Tool

Comment: using a shortcut?

Comment: @SmartManoj If you're referring to a ***keyboard*** shortcut, you likely can edit the properties of the *Windows* shortcut to the Snipping Tool and assign a *keyboard* shortcut.

Comment: In Snipping Tool, a region should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

using pyautogui one can take a regional screenshot. [Read more here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 300, 400))
```

You could bind a key press to a regional screenshot

Comment: The region is dynamic. Did you check the accepted answer? I already commented it. Did you flag it?